# bootstrap version used in apache-zeppelin 0.10.0

Tags: tags, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to identify the exact version of bootstrap used in apache-zeppelin version 0.10.0.  How do I do that?

I have reviewed the dependency files in the github repo, and it seems to indicate that bootstrap v3.4.0 was used on zeppelin version 0.10.0 but when reviewing the app and vendor js files using developer tool the comments indicate that bootstrap v3.2.0 is used on zeppelin version 0.10.0.
I was expecting to view bootstrap v3.4.0 or higher in the vendor js comments on my zeppelin version 0.10.0 local instance.  Or reference of bootstrap v3.4.0 or higher on any of the source files when exploring the details of zeppelin version 0.10.0.